# remove double IP adresses from log files

Tags: linux, logging, ip

I have some log-files. In the log-files are some lines with double IP-addresses.
Example:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2021:10:26:41 +0100] "GET /file"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2021:10:26:44 +0100] "GET /file"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2021:10:26:47 +0100] "GET /file"
```

I know that the timestamp is different, but this is not important. Now i want to remove all except one entry. Note: I don´t know the IP address in the logs so the tool / filter should find duplicates automatically.

Thank you!

Comment: Which entry do you want to retain, the first or the last?

Comment: i think the last one is ok

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '{ map[$1]=$0 } END { for ( i in map ) { print map[i] } }' *.log
```

Create an array map using the field space separated field as the index and the line as the value as we process each line of the file. At the end of the file processing, loop through the array printing the values/lines.